# Python : Change values in a column based on multiple conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe as below:

| Team | Name | Position | FieldPosition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | Striker | Front |
| A | Carl | Defender | Back |
| A | Alex | Fill | None |
| A | Ron | Midfielder | Middle |
|  |  |  |  |
| B | Tyler | Striker | Front |
| B | Chad | Defender | Back |
| B | Guy | Goalkeeper | Back |
| B | Tom | Fill | None |
|  |  |  |  |
| C | James | Fill | None |
| C | Lucas | Defender | Back |
| C | Ben | Midfielder | Middle |
| C | Noah | Goalkeeper | Back |

I want to change the 'None' value in FieldPosition column to either 'Front, 'Middle' or 'Back' based on the Position column.

Each team will always have 1 Front,2 Backs and 1 Middle for the FieldPosition Column.
Striker will always be Front, Defender will always be Back and Midfielder will always be Middle.

For example: Fill position in team A will have a 'Back' FieldPosition
Fill position in team B will have a 'Middle' FieldPosition
Fill position in team C will have a 'Front' FieldPosition

I am guessing creating a function with loop and if-statements will solve this since there are more than 20 Teams. How can I do this?

---

Final answer should be as below:

| Team | Name | Position | FieldPosition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | Striker | Front |
| A | Carl | Defender | Back |
| A | Alex | Fill | *Back* |
| A | Ron | Midfielder | Middle |
|  |  |  |  |
| B | Tyler | Striker | Front |
| B | Chad | Defender | Back |
| B | Guy | Goalkeeper | Back |
| B | Tom | Fill | *Middle* |
|  |  |  |  |
| C | James | Fill | *Front* |
| C | Lucas | Defender | Back |
| C | Ben | Midfielder | Middle |
| C | Noah | Goalkeeper | Back |

Comment: Do you always have one missing value?

Comment: @mozway for this example it is one value but can be more than 1 value

Answer (score 1):

We can write a function that subtracts the FieldPositions from the required set and fills in the missing one per Team:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from collections import Counter

csv = """
Team    Name    Position    FieldPosition
A   John    Striker Front
A   Carl    Defender    Back
A   Alex    Fill    None
A   Ron Midfielder  Middle
B   Tyler   Striker Front
B   Chad    Defender    Back
B   Guy Goalkeeper  Back
B   Tom Fill    None
C   James   Fill    None
C   Lucas   Defender    Back
C   Ben Midfielder  Middle
C   Noah    Goalkeeper  Back"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep = '\t')

correct_values = ['Front','Back','Back','Middle']

def fill_none(lst):
    c = Counter(correct_values)-Counter(lst)-Counter(['None'])
    return list(c.elements())[0]

df['FieldPosition'] = np.where(df['FieldPosition'] == 'None',
                               df.groupby('Team').FieldPosition.transform(fill_none),
                               df['FieldPosition'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Counter` difference after mapping the fixed positions:

```
from collections import Counter

ref = Counter({'Front': 1, 'Middle': 1, 'Back': 2})

positions = {'Striker': 'Front', 'Defender': 'Back', 'Midfielder': 'Middle'}

df['FieldPosition'] = df['Position'].map(positions).fillna(df['FieldPosition'].replace({'None': float('nan')}))

def guess_missing(x):
    c = ref-Counter(x)
    if len(c) == 1:
        return next(iter(c))

df['FieldPosition'] = df['FieldPosition'].fillna(df.groupby('Team')['FieldPosition'].transform(guess_missing))
```

Output:

```
   Team   Name    Position FieldPosition
0     A   John     Striker         Front
1     A   Carl    Defender          Back
2     A   Alex        Fill          Back
3     A    Ron  Midfielder        Middle
4     B  Tyler     Striker         Front
5     B   Chad    Defender          Back
6     B    Guy  Goalkeeper          Back
7     B    Tom        Fill        Middle
8     C  James        Fill         Front
9     C  Lucas    Defender          Back
10    C    Ben  Midfielder        Middle
11    C   Noah  Goalkeeper          Back
```